# How to use mouse event for adding sprite Cocos2d-js

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I'm already trying but it's not what I'm expecting.

I want create something when my mouse pointing a sprite, that sprite glowing or have red border or something notice you that mouse pointing that sprite. in this case I'm calling another sprite with same sprite but more brighter.

it's not really a sprite, I have background like a sprite i want, so here the code pointing specific location from my background

```
Objs.aSprite_1st12 = new cc.Node();
Objs.aSprite_1st12.setContentSize(100,100);
Objs.aSprite_1st12.setAnchorPoint(0.5, 0.5);
Objs.aSprite_1st12.setScaleX(1.4);
Objs.aSprite_1st12.setScaleY(0.4);
Objs.aSprite_1st12.setRotation(25);
Objs.aSprite_1st12.setSkewX(10);
Objs.aSprite_1st12.setSkewY(-12);
Objs.aSprite_1st12.setPosition(cc.p(474,263));
this.addChild(Objs.aSprite_1st12, 10);
```

and i'm calling function mouse event

```
mouseEvent(this);
```

here the function is

```
function mouseEvent(that){
cc.eventManager.addListener({
        event:cc.EventListener.MOUSE,
        onMouseMove: function (event){
            var target = event.getCurrentTarget();
            var locationInNode = Objs.aSprite_1st12;
            var s = target.getContentSize();
            var rect = cc.rect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
            if (cc.rectContainsPoint(rect, locationInNode)) {
                var sprite1 = new cc.Sprite.create(Objs.sidechip);
                sprite1.setPosition(cc.p(474,263));
                sprite1.setScale(0.3);
                that.addChild(sprite1,0);
            }
        }
    }, that);
}
```

this code working, and a new sprite added in specific location I want it when the mouse is moving, but the problem is whenever the mouse move that sprite always added. i just want if that mouse pointing `Objs.aSprite_1st12`, new sprite added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the code exactly what i want it.

```
var sprite1 = new cc.Sprite.create(Objs.sidechip);
                        sprite1.setPosition(cc.p(474,263));
                        sprite1.setScale(0.3);
                        sprite1.setVisible (false);
                        this.addChild(sprite1,0);
    cc.eventManager.addListener(
    {
        event:cc.EventListener.MOUSE,

        onMouseMove: function (event)
        {
            var n = Math.floor(event.getLocationX());
            var m = Math.floor(event.getLocationY());
            if (n >= 396 && n <= 556 && m >= 216 && m <= 303){
            cc.log ("ikeh");    
            sprite1.setVisible (true);
            }else{
                sprite1.setVisible (false);
            }
        }
    }, this);
```

so I just add the sprite I want it first and `setVisible(false);` then, when mouse pointed between `(n >= 396 && n <= 556 && m >= 216 && m <= 303)` it's `setVisible(true);`.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware what `Objs.aSprite_1st12` actually is I'm sure that the code you've shown

```
var target = event.getCurrentTarget();
var locationInNode = Objs.aSprite_1st12;
```

treats ANY cc.Node as target. So if you want it to trigger ONLY on `Objs.aSprite_1st12` hover, and, hopefully `Objs.aSprite_1st12` is a cc.Node instance, not just your sprite resource, you need to change

```
var s = target.getContentSize();
var rect = cc.rect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
if (cc.rectContainsPoint(rect, locationInNode)) {
```

to

```
 var s = Objs.aSprite_1st12.getContentSize();
    var rect = cc.rect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
    if (cc.rectContainsPoint(rect, locationInNode)) {
```

Right?

Comment: yeah you got the point there, i notice it after you tell me `var target = event.getCurrentTarget();`is location where `onMouseMove: function (event){` move, so it will call new sprite whenever mouse is move.  i'm also change code like you said, but new sprite never show. thanks btw

Comment: ah, thanks to you again, I'm notice it how to make it what i want. I'm posting the answer